# Applying shopping cart price rule to Customer purchasing from a gift registry

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I would like to know if it's possible to apply discounts to customers purchasing from an existing gift registry

Or is there a plugin/extension i can use that does this?

Please help.

Thanks